# Set DSN for all reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a Report folder on Report server and this folder have 73 reports. I have created the shared data source (DSN). Now, I want to change the data source of all reports in one go. Is there any option to set common dsn for all report?

I have right click on report and selected manage tab. After that in property window I have set the data source and its done successfully,

But doing same way for all report will take more time, so I want any shortcut for that.

Comment: If you're using a shared source just change the connection string of that source; all the reports using it will be effected. Don't change the source they are using, change the source itself.

Comment: And if you're not using a shared datasource, take the time to change it now as it will save this issue from happening in future.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. SSRS has very few bulk operations like that. The reports though, are just XML (called RDL). One option would be to modify one, find out the change that was made, and to write a small program to update all the reports.

Comment: We often do the same for checking all the margins are correct, changing embedded logos, changing embedded VB script functions, etc.